# Minimizing quadratic forms and choosing sufficient step size

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to minimize the following:

$P(x_{k+1}) = f(x_k) + \nabla f (x_k) \cdot (-h_k \nabla f(x_k)) + \frac{1}{2}(-h_k \nabla f(x_k))^T Hf(x_k) (-h_k \nabla f(x_k))$

I know that minimizing the quadratic form is by solving $Ax = b$ i.e. $x = A^{-1}b$, so how can I choose $h_k$ to minimize $P$.

Comment: What are you assumptions on $f$? Is it convex and real-valued?
Also, this is just semantics, but the correct terminology is that you're **minimizing $f$**. The method you minimize $f$ is by implementing the Newton method you've written above. It doesn't make a ton of sense to minimize an iteration!